# R String generate from Data Frame Column

Tags: r, data-analysis

Suppose I have a Dataframe in R with two columns

```
Name,Number

sample Dataset
"PETER","15401",
"SAMMY","68475"
```

now for each row i want to create a new column with the values as `<1st Digit in the Reverse of Number><First 3 digits in name><2nd Digit in Reverse of the number.>`

so the solution for the above dataset should be

```
for 1.
"1PET0"
for 2
"5SAM7"
```

I am a newbie in R so please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Can you also update with some example/expected output as earlier

Comment: It's very confusing when you add a second question to your question after asking it. What you should do, if you want help with part 2 of your question, is accept an answer to part1, then ask a new question based on Part 2. Make sure to include your data and the desired result

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste` with `substr`

```
df1$newcol <- with(df1, paste0(substr(Number, nchar(Number), nchar(Number)),
            substr(Name, 1, 3), 
           substr(Number, nchar(Number)-1, nchar(Number)-1)))
df1$newcol
#[1] "1PET0" "5SAM7"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("PETER", "SAMMY"), Number = c(15401L, 
 68475L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: @MRIDULMITTAL  It is `substr` to substring the strings based on some numeric index

Comment: @MRIDULMITTAL  sure can you invite me

Comment: @MRIDULMITTAL  Can you please update in your post.  It is so hard to read from the comments

Answer (score 0):

The package `stringi` comes in handy because of its `stri_reverse`-function:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Name,Number
PETER,15401
SAMMY,68475", sep = ",") 

dat$new <- paste0(substr(stringi::stri_reverse(dat$Number), 1, 1), 
                  substr(dat$Name, 1, 3), 
                  substr(stringi::stri_reverse(dat$Number), 2, 2))

dat
#>    Name Number   new
#> 1 PETER  15401 1PET0
#> 2 SAMMY  68475 5SAM7
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    
read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Name,Number
PETER,15401
SAMMY,68475", sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(new = paste0(substr(stringi::stri_reverse(Number), 1, 1), 
                      substr(Name, 1, 3), 
                      substr(stringi::stri_reverse(Number), 2, 2)))
#>    Name Number   new
#> 1 PETER  15401 1PET0
#> 2 SAMMY  68475 5SAM7
```